# How do I combine string Pandas columns with null values and a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine to 2 Pandas columns with this format:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | '1' |
| '12' | '34' |
| '56' | '78' |
| NaN | '90' |

Column B will always have a value and I want to combine if Column A has a value, otherwise, I will just keep B. This is the basic function that I tried to do for this

```
def func():
  if Column A is None:
    return Column B
  else:
    return Column A + '/' +  Column B
```

This is what happens if I run this:

| Column C |
| --- |
| NaN |
| 12/34 |
| 56/78 |
| NaN |

This is the expected output that I want to achieve where I keep column B if column A is Null but my code is not working.

| Column C |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 12/34 |
| 56/78 |
| 90 |

Comment: `np.where(df['Column A'].notnull(), df['Column A'] + '/' + df['Column B'], df['Column B'])`

Comment: @user3483203 thanks! This worked! the where function seems to be working like an if statement no? Would you be able to explain to me why my function wasn't working?

Comment: `np.nan` is not `None`, so that path is never followed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Numpy `where()` function for creating the conditional statement. Please sample code below

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {"Column A": [None,'12','56',None],
        'Column B': ['1','34','78','90']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Column C'] = np.where(df['Column A'].notnull(),df['Column A'] + '/' + df['Column B'],df['Column B'])
print(df)
```

### Output:

```
  Column A Column B Column C
0     None        1        1
1       12       34    12/34
2       56       78    56/78
3     None       90       90
```

Reference:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Thanks for this! Would you be able to explain to me why my function wasn't working?